# Zooming works only when hovering on the dots in scatterplot

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to implement a scatter plot with zooming capability with D3. I have generated the plot and the visualization,it can zoom in and out only when the mouse cursor is over the data points. In other words, when the mouse is on anywhere other than the dots, I am unable to zoom.

I have been searching and trying a number of examples from the Internet, but I had no luck. Please check the code residing in this link: https://github.com/e-kaya/scatter.git What do you think I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the zoom function on the `.dots`.

```
svg.select(".dots").call(zoom);
```

Try binding the zoom function to the `<svg>`.

```
d3.select('svg').call(zoom);
```

depending on your requirement you may have to tweak the zoomed function as well.

```
function zoomed() {
    d3.select('svg).attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

This will zoom your svg container.

Comment: Of course, how couldn't I notice that? Thanks for quick response!